# Django order by on queryset objects

Tags: python, django

I have the following admin action below that exports data to a CSV file, I'm struggling to figure out how to order by on the queryset parameter:

```
import csv
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.http import HttpResponse

def export_as_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    """
    Generic csv export admin action.
    """
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        raise PermissionDenied
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.csv' % unicode(opts).replace('.', '_')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    field_names = [field.name for field in opts.fields]
    # Write a first row with header information
    writer.writerow(field_names)
    # Write data rows
    for obj in queryset:
        writer.writerow([getattr(obj, field) for field in field_names])
    return response
export_as_csv.short_description = "Export selected objects as csv file"
```

I thought the following would have worked:

queryset = queryset.objects.order_by('practice')

However I get the following error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i think you want

```
queryset = queryset.order_by('practice')
```

(no `objects`)